# Maven: ignore the distribution management repositories in transitive dependencies

Tags: maven, pom.xml, transitive-dependency

i have a multi module project. moduleA is download dependencies dep1, dep2.
now dep1 has its own repositories(nexus-snapshot, maven central, xyz) defined and has dependencies, which attempt to be downloaded from it own list of repositories.

now of one of the repository is decommissioned and since i dont own the dep1. i cant take off the decomissioned repository in distribution management.

my jenkins waits for 1 hr searching artifacts of the transitive dependencies in the decommissioned repository. how can i avoid this

Comment: Use a repository manager...and setup up a settings.xml configuration to consume only from a repository manager .... otherwise you have to change the pom files and remove the old repos...

Answer (score 0):

Use a `settings.xml` with an appropriate mirror.

The best resolution is to follow khmarbaise's advice and use an Artifactory or Nexus server as mirror.

Second best solution is to redirect all repositories but the ones you really need to MavenCentral.